# What are Ubuntu Vad Files?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I am a new user of Ubuntu and have been seeing VAD files in Ubuntu.  What are they and what are they used for?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it means "Virtuoso Application Distribution", and from the Ubuntu [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/virtuoso-opensource) project page, this is what I found:

> Virtuoso is a high-performance object-relational SQL database. As a database, it provides transactions, a smart SQL compiler, powerful stored-procedure language with optional Java and .Net server-side hosting, hot backup, SQL-99 support and more. It has all major data-access interfaces, such as ODBC, JDBC, ADO .Net and OLE/DB.

I think the VAD files you are talking about are just SQL databases, but I'm not sure.  Could you provide an example?

EDIT: They could also be ATI driver files.

Comment: Good point.  It might not be an inherently Ubuntu thing like I thought it was.  Thanks!